# Cannot compile iOS project, Firebase header file not found

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, cocoapods

The project previously compiled using Xcode 14.3, but I'm now having issues on Xcode 15. One of the project's file cannot find the header file located in one of my libs. This library is associated to the project as a pod.

```
// custom class imported from my other lib
#import "fireBaseIntegration.h"
```

Error:

> 'fireBaseIntegration.h' file not found

Xcode version: 15.0.1
CocoaPods version: 1.11.2
Minimum deployment: iOS 13

I have tried enabling/disabling `ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES/NO` as recommended in some other threads, but the issue remained.

I also tried flagging the run scripts with `always_out_of_date=1` to make sure no run scripts were skipped, but that did not fix it.